# Convert json timestamp to nornal java timestamp

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can i convert a Javascript timestamp in JSON to java timestamp?

```
Json timestamp Example: 1365427692
```

Comment: Looks like timestamp in seconds, just multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds for Java timestamp.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp  from the question: java.util.Date time=new java.util.Date((long)timeStamp*1000);

Answer (score 0):

```
private Date JSONTarihConvert(String tarih) throws ParseException{
    long timestamp = getTimeStampFromTarih(tarih);
    return new Date(timestamp);
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984199/how-can-i-convert-json-date-to-java-date)

Comment: where is getTimeStampFromTarih function ?

Comment: it is just a function to get the actual timestamp: `1365427692`, in your example

Comment: you just copy and paste the same code but don't explain where the function come from. there's a comment on the question that explain it.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern way is with java.time classes.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1365427692L );
```

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.